# CSS Select all inputs except those inside DIV containig class

Tags: html, jquery, css-selectors

I'm trying to disable all form inputs except those that are inside the

`<div class="class class2 w--tab-active">...</div>`

For some reason, this disables also aforementioned inputs:

```
$('form :input:not(.w--tab-active)').prop('disabled',true);
```

I tried also:

```
$('form :not(.w--tab-active) :input').prop('disabled',true);
```

Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: Remove the space before the `:not()` selector. Also you can use the filter method to filter the result: `$('form input').filter('form:not(.w--tab-active input)').prop('disabled, true);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this :

```js
$('form input').not($('.w--tab-active').find('input')).prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$("form input:not('form .w--tab-active input')").each(function(){
   console.log(this);
   $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

See [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/crnastena/kypjq8Lm/1/)